# Question about the use of parentheses in functions

Tags: javascript

I'm starting to study javascript, I implemented this little snippet of code. I spent a long time trying to run the browser until I realized that the problem was calling functions with and without parentheses, note the commented lines.

```
var buttonElement = document.querySelector('#app button');
var tarefaDigitada = document.querySelector('#app input');
var listElement = document.querySelector('#app ul');

var todos = ['Cofee', 'Beer', 'Water'];

function renderTodos() {

    listElement.innerHTML = '';

    for (todo of todos) {
        var todoElement = document.createElement('li');
        var todoText = document.createTextNode(todo); 

        todoElement.appendChild(todoText);
        listElement.appendChild(todoElement);

    }
}

function addTodo() {
    var text = tarefaDigitada.value;
    console.log(tarefaDigitada.value);
    todos.push(text);
    tarefaDigitada.value = '';
    renderTodos();//No parentheses doesn't work

}
renderTodos();
buttonElement.onclick = addTodo;//With parentheses does not work
```

Even without parameters is necessary to put parentheses? Why on the call to onclick I can not put?

Comment: Any decent tutorial should explain this. If you read one that did not, find another, because the one you read was either too compact/short, or bad.

Comment: Parenthesis execute a function. `renderTodos()` causes `renderTodos` to run right then. `buttonElement.onclick = addTodo` is passing a reference to a function. It will be executed later (like when a user clicks). In this case you *don't* want it to run right now.

Answer (score 1):

When you want to call a function in that line itself you add parenthesis whereas in the other case you are telling JS to call the function internally whenever the button is clicked not right then.

Answer (score 1):

There must be dupes of this question around SO. When you do `onclick = addTodo()` you're calling the function and setting `onclick` to whatever the function returns. You don't want that; you want to set `onclick` to the function itself, hence no parentheses.

Comment: There are around 294356239478234 dupes of this, e.g. (but not limited to) a million questions about `setTimeout(fn(), 1000)` vs `setTimeout(fn, 1000)`

Comment: so I found one and voted to close as a dupe...